# highlighting a longer selection using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzm2o6r2/)

Im trying to highlight text using Jquery, it works with shorter selections(like 3 to 5 words), but not longer selections(see image attached)

When you click the highlight link the selected text should change to yellow color.

[image]

Whenever i try to do longer selections i get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

You can find the whole code on the [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bzm2o6r2/)

Comment: I just added some console.log instructions in your JS to see what is the content of the variables. See this http://jsfiddle.net/bzm2o6r2/1/

And it seems that your existsInElements and exactElement always refer to $(body), but seems like the selector contains has a limit, when exceeded it doesn't seem to find the object

Comment: I am actually not seeing the issue described in your fiddle.   I have been able to select the same paragraph you are trying to do in your image and it highlights the entire item as expected.   The only place so far that I see that it is not highlight is when I also include the span tag for source reference.  Using IE10.   However, I do see your described issue in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).on( "click", ".share_link", function() {

    var sel = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange(); // FF : IE
    if(sel.getRangeAt){ // thats for FF
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var newNode = document.createElement("span");
    newNode.setAttribute('class', 'high');
    range.surroundContents(newNode);
    } else { //and thats for IE7
    sel.pasteHTML('<span class="someclass">'+sel.htmlText+'</span>');


    }
    });
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/yc2gouk3/

This works well with long *paragraph* selection